# .NET CORE 3.0 GetTokenAsync Authorization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer MyMagicToken
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:63304
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/fooBar
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36
```

I am sending the above request up to my WebApI 2 controller. The controller is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute

For some reason the first line of my `AUTHORIZE` attribute is returning null

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext 
    context, HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var token = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
```

How should I change my http request to make `var token` equal `MyMagicToken` ?

In `ApiStartup` I have

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: do you have the request middleware?

Comment: not in the `AUTHORIZATION` code, I have `ErrorMiddleWare` set up.

Comment: make sure the authentication one is done

Comment: @DanielA.White I modified the question with adding the middleware. Is this what you ment?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the Bearer token just get the value of `Authorization` header and trim it like this:

```
            var authorizationHeader = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            var tokenValue = authorizationHeader.First().Replace("Bearer ", "");
```

Comment: Your solution works, I want to do it with `var token = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;` . I am curious as to why the above code doesnt work.

Comment: it's hard to tell without the whole Startup configuration context :P. I'm glad it works for you

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you have to specify the authentication schema like this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="kind of yout auth schema")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `GetTokenAsync()` the issue is with the token itself, The token has to be a JWT access formatted token. `GetTokenAsync()` does not go through the HTTP headers looking for a header with `Authorization` and just takes the value inside. It goes through the HTTP headers looking for an `Authorization` header *AND* has a properly formatted JWT token